# JFormatedTextField DocumentListener trows java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, swing, illegalstateexception, numberformatexception, documentlistener

My program is supposed to print a price of a transaction according to a quantity of products the user wants to get, the user type on a JFormatedTextField and a documentListener notify changes, but when the user errase the hole thing the program dies.
`

```
    final JFormattedTextField quantityTextField = new JFormattedTextField((Integer) null);
    //Check for changes.
    quantityTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
          @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              if(quantityTextField.getText()!=null){
                  totalPrice = (Integer.valueOf(quantityTextField.getText()).intValue())* unitaryPrice ;
                    priceToShow.setText(""+totalPrice);
                  }else{
                      totalPrice=0;
                      quantityTextField.setText("0");
                  }
          }
          @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {   //Here is the problem the text on the field isnt equals to "" or null (when is empty)
              if(quantityTextField.getText()!=null && quantityTextField.getText()!=""){
                  totalPrice = (Integer.valueOf(cuantityTextField.getText()).intValue())* unitaryPrice ;
                  priceToShow.setText(""+totalPrice);
              }else{
                  totalPrice=0;
                  quantityTextField.setText("0");
              }
          }
          @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
              System.out.println("\n++ Insert");
              totalPrice = (Integer.valueOf(quantityTextField.getText()).intValue())* unitaryPrice ;
                priceToShow.setText(""+totalPrice);
          }
    });
```

When its empty after user errase the compiler trows java.lang.IllegalStateException, for converting an "" into a int. the if clause in the removeUpdate listener should handle if the text is empty or null and set the total price to 0, yet the condition is never reach and i dond`t know why.

please help.

Comment: You can't modify the text component from within a Documentalistener.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

BTW `quantityTextField.getText()!="`" won't work. Use equals() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `quantityTextField.getText().length() > 0` to avoid dealing with blank spaces.